# SQL JOIN on all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, table A

```
Key     String
1       Val1
1       Val2
2       Val1
3       Val1
3       Val2
```

that I'd like to join on table B

```
Key     String
1       Val1
2       Val2
```

where I'd like to get only values in table A that match to all of the contents of table A. The result in this example would give me keys 1 & 3 from table. Those are the only records where there is an exact match with table B.

How do I write that SQL, using SQL Server?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Key
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN tableB AS b ON a.Key = b.Key AND a.String = b.String
GROUP BY a.Key
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.String) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(String)) 
                                   FROM TableB)
```